# linkisted have a pointer for required data

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list , which has full information

```
    typdef struct details
     {
      struct details *head, *next, *curr;
      char* values;
    }


    Details *fyllinfo ; //(this strcuct has full information)
```

/* fyllinfo this has been filled with many vallues*/

Now I need to copy the pointers to new list which can point only my required or matched data
        Details *required;

```
    char* myValue;


details *pstPtr =fyllinfo->head;

details *required = (details*) malloc(
            sizeof(details));
required->head = required->next = NULL;

while(pstPtr != NULL)
{
    if(NULL == pstPtr->values) goto NEXT;
        printf("UUID FOUND IS [%s] and comapre with [%s] ",pstPtr->values,myvalue);

    if(strCmp(pstPtr->values,myvalue)==0)
    {

        if(required->head == NULL)
            {
                required->head = required->curr = pstPtr;
            }
        else
        {

            required->next = pstPtr;
            required->curr->next = pstPtr;
        }
    }
    NEXT: pstPtr = pstPtr->next;
}
```

My Required ptr should have the pointer to only matched  values

My code only points the first matched data and it has unmatched data in reuired->next  pointer

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: Actually I have to store ptr for the matched data , for example if I have data store like this "1fuuid"  "Yuyuuid" "1fuuid" "aauuid" "bcnuuid" "ifuuid" in fyllinfo list , I have to have only "1fuuid" "1fuuid" "1fuuid", in the required pointer head and next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works now... you just need to put some effort to understand it. you should be able to print the values. see how values are stored now.

```
details *pstPtr = fyllinfo;

    details *required = NULL; //(details*)malloc(
      details *head=NULL;
    while (pstPtr != NULL)
    {
        if (1 == pstPtr->values) 
        printf("UUID FOUND IS [%d] and comapre with [%d] \n", pstPtr->values, 1);

        if (pstPtr->values==1)
        {

            if (required == NULL)
            {
                required = (details*)malloc( sizeof(details));
                head = required;
                required->head = required->curr = pstPtr;
                required->next = NULL;
            }
            else
            {

                required->next = (details*)malloc(sizeof(details));
                required = required->next;
                required->next = NULL;
                required->curr = pstPtr;
            }
        }
        pstPtr = pstPtr->next;
    }




void  display(struct details *r)
{
    // r = fyllinfo;
    if (r == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    while (r != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", r->curr->values);
        r = r->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I dont want to copy the value and duplicate it , is it not possible to store only the pointers, so that it should have pointers to only values matched ?

Comment: you can just store pointer. but then you should not do this. required->curr->next = pstPtr; becuase by require-> curr you will will move to the original list and next will be called of the original list.

Comment: I tried This in my else part required->next = pstPtr;          required =  required->next;  but its not having data of all the matched pointers.

Comment: details *head=NULL; head=required, I did not get  Why this being used.  Still its printing the only first value, I am trying to print from required->head .

Comment: I even added the display method